# Hard drive goes unpartitioned after failed attempt to create bootable. Possible to revert it back to what it used to be?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

So this is what happened. I created a 3G ExFAT parition in a WD MyPassport that already had 6 partitions (about half are HFS Plus; rest ExFAT) using Disk Ulitiy on my mac, as I planned to make this 3G drive bootable for Ubunto installation on my desktop. I then used [ISO to USB (a windows program)](http://www.isotousb.com/) to create the bootable drive but for some reasons it failed miserably. After that the ExFAT paritions no long showed up on my desktop and the file system of my harddrive displayed RAW in Disk Management.

[image]

So I performed a quick diagnostics task using WD Drive Utilities. It passed the task.

[image]

But using DiskPart I discovered that there was only one partition left in the disk.
[image]

And it is indeed true that its file system is RAW.
[image: oh no]

Is there a way to revert the harddrive back to what it used to be? Or all I can do now is try to recover the files? (since it's only the pointers that are gone.)

Comment: The partitions are gone.  You **might** be able to recover the files if no other data has been written. Use file recover software of your choice to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) on the disk. In particular, try loading the backup partition table from the end of the disk, as described in the [`gdisk` documentation on recovering from problems.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) You may need to read the [introduction to GPT](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html) in the `gdisk` documentation and/or at least skim the [Wikipedia entry on GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) to learn the basics of GPT structure so you have some idea of what you're doing.

If this doesn't work, it's possible that [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) will enable you to recover at least some of your partitions.

Note that even if you can recover data in either of these ways, you might not recover *everything*. In particular, it's likely that the first partition or two on your disk has been so badly damaged that it might not be recoverable.